# Remove duplicate lines in braces

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I a have file that contains:

```
l1_lololo {
    abcdef
    vgjhklfgkchbnvu
    gfuhjfythkjbgftyhkjgyftuihgt6
    deefgik
    abcdef
}

l2_blabla {
    123456
    vgghyfthjfgtrdygfhhbnvu
    gfuhjgvftdyfgvjgyftuihgt6
    deiulouk
    123456
}
```

I need to check text in braces with sed/awk/bash/etc. and remove duplicates of lines, leaving only first of recurring line in each braces, I need to get this:

```
l1_lololo {
    abcdef
    vgjhklfgkchbnvu
    gfuhjfythkjbgftyhkjgyftuihgt6
    deefgik
}

l2_blabla {
    123456
    vgghyfthjfgtrdygfhhbnvu
    gfuhjgvftdyfgvjgyftuihgt6
    deiulouk
}
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you can guarantee that the blocks end with a line containing only `}`, it could be done as simply as:

```
awk '/^}$/ {delete a} !a[$0]++' input
```

If you need a more robust solution, perhaps just add some whitespace to the pattern to match the end of a block.  But if you want a full parser and want to match braces carefully, `awk` is probably not suited for the task.

Comment: But if blocks ends with some spaces before brace and may be contain, for example, ';' after brace, what I need to change in command?

Comment: You just need to change the pattern to match it.  For example `/^ *}/` might suit you. (Matching any line that begins with whitespace followed by `}`)

Comment: @ComptrollerChanel if in your real data the block  "ends with some spaces before brace and may be contain, for example, ';' after brace" then you should, obviously, include those cases in the sample input/output in your question. All we have to go on when trying to answer your question is the info you provide in your question so it's important for your example to be truly representative of your real data. `/}/` is all you need if there can't be a `}` anywhere else in  your data as shown in your example.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to other languages, this is really easy to do in tcl thanks to the input being in tcl list format, allowing you to use it to do all the parsing without any potentially fragile regular expressions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require Tcl 8.5
foreach {key lst} [read stdin] {
    foreach item $lst { dict set seen $item 1 }
    puts "$key {\n\t[join [dict keys $seen] \n\t]\n}\n"
    unset seen
}
```

Example:

```
$ ./dedup < input.txt
l1_lololo {
        abcdef
        vgjhklfgkchbnvu
        gfuhjfythkjbgftyhkjgyftuihgt6
        deefgik
}

l2_blabla {
        123456
        vgghyfthjfgtrdygfhhbnvu
        gfuhjgvftdyfgvjgyftuihgt6
        deiulouk
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Desired result can be achieved with following code (data stored in a hash)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = do{ local $/; <DATA> };      # read whole data

my %seen;
my %records = $data =~ /(\w+)\s+\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}/sg;     # split into records

while( my($k,$v) = each %records ) {    # for each record split into array
    my @array = map { if( not $seen{$_} ) { $seen{$_} = 1; $_ } } split '\s+', $records{$k};    # store uniq elements
    pop @array;                         # pop out last empty element
    $records{$k} = \@array;             # store array in hash
}

while( my($k,$v) = each %records ) {    # each record
    say "$k = {";                       # output hash key
    say "\t$_" for @{$v};               # output each element of array
    say "}\n";                          # done
}

__DATA__
l1_lololo {
    abcdef
    vgjhklfgkchbnvu
    gfuhjfythkjbgftyhkjgyftuihgt6
    deefgik
    abcdef
}

l2_blabla {
    123456
    vgghyfthjfgtrdygfhhbnvu
    gfuhjgvftdyfgvjgyftuihgt6
    deiulouk
    123456
}
```

Output

```
l1_lololo = {
        abcdef
        vgjhklfgkchbnvu
        gfuhjfythkjbgftyhkjgyftuihgt6
        deefgik
}

l2_blabla = {
        123456
        vgghyfthjfgtrdygfhhbnvu
        gfuhjgvftdyfgvjgyftuihgt6
        deiulouk
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\S+ \{/{:a;N;s/((\n[^\n]*)(\n.*)*)\2$/\1/;/\n\}$/!ba}' file
```

If a line begins with some text followed by a `{`, append the next line and remove the last line if it matches a preceding line. Repeat the latter until a line containing only a `}` and print the result.